# Limit of $a_n = -\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right)$ (proof)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Warning to anyone who stumbles upon this: It is wrong completely and utterly don't use it for reference, thank you Don and Gerry for helping me see this

So my first question is asking whether or not the following is a valid proof:

Claim: $a_n = -\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty$

Given $\epsilon > 0$ let $N = \Big[ \frac{\pi}{8 \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) } + \frac{1}{4} \Big] + 1 \; \forall \; 0 \le \epsilon \le 2$ so then it is true that

$$
\forall \; n \ge N = \Big[ \frac{\pi}{8 \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) } + \frac{1}{4} \Big] + 1 > \frac{\pi}{8 \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) } + \frac{1}{4} \\
\implies 8n > \frac{\pi}{\arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right)} + 2 \\
\implies 8n - 2 > \frac{\pi}{\arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right)} \\
\implies \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) > \frac{\pi}{8n-2} = \Bigl\lvert \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \Bigr\rvert \\
\implies \epsilon - 1 > \cos \left( \Bigl\lvert \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \Bigl\lvert \right) = \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert \\\\
\implies \epsilon > \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert + 1 = \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert + \lvert 1 \rvert \ge \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) + 1 \Bigr\rvert \\\\
\iff \epsilon > \Bigl\lvert \, - \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) - 1 \Bigr\rvert
$$
and then it's trivial to see that the above still holds for $\epsilon > 2$

$\therefore \; a_n \to 1$

The second question is silly since the first part is invalid...

My next question is how come you cannot replace `1` with `-1` throughout this proof to show that the limit converges to `-1`. I'm pretty sure it goes to 1 so that's why I picked `1` but wouldn't replacing the `1` with `-1` simply change the absolute value to be from | 1 | to the |- 1| where both are equivalent to 1?

In other words why is this wrong?

$$
\forall \; n \ge N = \Big[ \frac{\pi}{8 \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) } + \frac{1}{4} \Big] + 1 > \frac{\pi}{8 \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) } + \frac{1}{4} \\
\implies 8n > \frac{\pi}{\arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right)} + 2 \\
\implies 8n - 2 > \frac{\pi}{\arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right)} \\
\implies \arccos \left( \epsilon - 1 \right) > \frac{\pi}{8n-2} = \Bigl\lvert \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \Bigr\rvert \\
\implies \epsilon - 1 > \cos \left( \Bigl\lvert \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \Bigl\lvert \right) = \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert \\\\
\implies \epsilon > \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert + 1 = \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) \Bigr\rvert + \lvert -1 \rvert \ge \Bigl\lvert \, \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) - 1 \Bigr\rvert \\\\
\iff \epsilon > \Bigl\lvert \, - \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right) + 1 \Bigr\rvert
$$
which would then lead me to $a_n \to -1$ rather than `1`

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Presumably, all these limits are as $n\to\infty$. If so, please edit this into the question.

Comment: Hollie Mollie, some calculations! Say: can't you use known facts about continuous functions?

Comment: Cosine is a decreasing function, so $\arccos a\lt b$ implies $a\gt\cos b$

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't think I follow but I'm guessing not (I'm learning fairly restrictively, pretending we don't know what a function is yet, only sequences)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yep, fixed in above I apologize

Comment: @GerryMyerson put that in an answer and it'll be marked as the answer... also help on the proof would be awesome ;D

Comment: I think your work is fine, though one of two words about steps with inequalities could help, for example 4 lines after "...so then it is true that...": why when you bring $\arccos(\epsilon-1)\,$ to the other side the inequality sign remains?

Comment: @DonAntonio I presume you're asking because arccos is a decreasing function so the sign should change?

Comment: If, for example, $\,\arccos(\epsilon-1)<0\,$ ....We know that multiplying\dividing an inequality *reverses* the inequality sign, for example $$3<4\Longrightarrow -3>-4\,$$

Comment: @DonAntonio right that's if you divide/multiply by a negative, $\arccos \theta $ is always positive though

Comment: @D, I'm not arguing that (and, go figure, I already knew that). I'm just saying that a word about those steps could perhaps help, in particular in basic exercises like this one. For example, noting that $\,8n-2>0\iff n>1/4\,$ , putting then absolute value in $\,\pi/(8n-2)\,$ seems pointless...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah ok I see - the absolute value is because I need the absolute value of $\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8n-2} \right)$ in order to form the definition of the limit of a sequence (which is with absolute values) but again I might just be acting silly as has been seen throughout this entire question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At request of OP: Cosine is a decreasing function, so $\arccos a\lt b$ implies $a\gt\cos b$.

Answer (score 3):

The cosine function is continuous everywhere so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8n-2}\right)=-\cos\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{8n-2}\right)=-\cos (0)=-1$$

Comment: I would use this but I have not been taught this property of limits of sequences

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)
= 1-2\sin^2(x)$
so
$1-\cos(x) = 2\sin^2(x/2)$.

If we can use $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$
then
$|1-\cos(x)| \le 2|x/2|^2 = |x|^2/2$
so
$|1-\cos\left (\frac{\pi}{8n-2}\right )|
\le \left ( \frac{\pi^2}{2(8n-2)^2}\right )
$
and the rest should be easy.